# Using Multiple ResultSet in JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, glassfish-4

I'm pretty new with JSP. 
I am trying to select 2 sql statements to produce 2 separate tables. I could successfully select 1 table,but when i tried 2 tables i can't get it to run.
What I did was.

setting up my connection:

```
<%
String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "supr";
String userId = "root";
String password = "secret";

try {
Class.forName(driverName);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
ResultSet resultSet2 = null;
%>
```

Connect and execute Query

```
<%
       try {
       connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
       connectionUrl + dbName, userId, password);
       statement = connection.createStatement();
       String sql = "SELECT con.container_id, con.con_location, con.con_status, concap.capacity FROM container con INNER JOIN con_capacity concap ON con.container_id = concap.container_id";

       String sql2 = "SELECT p.pipe_id, p.pipe_location, pd.PipeDis_date FROM pipe p JOIN pipe_disinfect pd ON p.pipe_id = pd.pipe_id ";
       resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
       resultSet2 = statement.executeQuery(sql2);
       %>
```

This first table works well alone.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
           <th>Container ID</th>
           <th>Location</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>Capacity</th>
           <th></th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           <%
           while (resultSet.next()) { %>
           <tr>
            <td><%=resultSet.getString("Container_ID")%></td>
            <td><%=resultSet.getString("Con_Location")%></td>
            <td><%=resultSet.getString("Con_Status")%></td>
            <td><%=resultSet.getString("Capacity")%></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Schedule</button></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
          <%
         }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       %>                                          
      </table>
```

But when I tried combining with a second table as below, then I cant get it to run.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
        <th>Pipe ID</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Last Disinfection</th>
        <th></th>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <%
        while (resultSet2.next()) { %>
        <tr>
         <td><%=resultSet2.getString("Pipe_ID")%></td>
         <td><%=resultSet2.getString("Pipe_Location")%></td>
         <td><%=resultSet2.getString("Pipe_LastDisinfect")%></td>
         <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Schedule</button></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
       <%  /**I'm getting an error on this line on eclipse****/
      }

     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>                                          
   </table>
```

and I got internal server error from GlassFish

Comment: remove the end tag "</tbody>" out of while loop and add it out of it  and paste the error log if is shown again

Answer (score 0):

Connections, statements and result sets must be `close()`d.
Hence reusing variables will not do.

`Class.forName` no longer is needed to load the database vendor specif library jar.

```
<%
    String sql = "SELECT con.container_id, con.con_location, con.con_status, "
        + " concap.capacity "
        + "FROM container con "
        + "INNER JOIN con_capacity concap ON con.container_id = concap.container_id";
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            connectionUrl + dbName, userId, password);
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
%>
...
<%
        }
    }
%>
```

Using the try-with-resources syntax above, the closes are done automatically even when returning or an exception is thrown.

Also this variable usage prevents the need to think of different names like `statement2`.